# i have a redirection rule of index.php in my htaccess and now if url contains index.php/anything then it should show error page with 404 code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the htaccess file with the following configuration, where I have redirected www.example.com/index.php to www.example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php/ /error-404 [P]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
```

But now I have some urls provided by Google webmaster tool which are showing soft 404 page and all the urls contains index.php

i.e. `www.example.com/index.php/anything`

I made it possible to show 404 page using htaccess, but it's not returning 404 response code. I want to show the 404 page along with the response code 404 in return.